# SQL Server 2012: Identify Columns dynamically in a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 50 Columns.
Ex. (Table: Col1,...Col50)

'N' number of Users fetch Cols based on their requirement. (Those cols might change dynamically). 
For ex.
User1: Col1..Col10
User2: Col4, Col5
User3: Col40..Col50
In future, the consumer / user may request more columns and even the number of users / consumer may gets increased.

Now, I need to create **only one VIEW** which should **dynamically select columns based on the User who is calling the VIEW**. Is it possible in SQL Server 2012? Any logic would be grateful please.

Comment: In the `view` and in the `function` (inline or table variable) you are always returning the same record sets. If you want to have different record sets, you can use stored procedure.

Comment: @gotqn: Thank you for your input. Yes we understand that our logic can be implemented in a stored procedure. But the requirement is to create a View and the logic implemented in it.

Answer (score 0):

A view is an object which shouldn't have dynamic properties, the only thing dynamic in a view should be the result set, as is intended for it's purpose.

You'd do much better creating a Stored Procedure to handle dynamic SELECT statements based on the user calling it.